# Is there a way to swap long (or double) and reference values on JVM stack?

Tags: jvm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

Let's say I have following bytecode sequence

```
aload 0 // this
lload 1
aload 3
```

For the sake of the question, let's assume that these instructions are generated by other code and I don't have control over it.

I need to swap last two items on a stack, a long and a reference. I can't do it with `swap`, cause `long` takes two slots on a stack and `swap` doesn't care about that.

I'll get something like this when loading the class:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    bytecode/generated/SomeClasName.someMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @18: swap
  Reason:
    Type long_2nd (current frame, stack[3]) is not assignable to category1 type
```

Is there a way to swap category1 and category2 types on a stack without resorting to locals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use
    [`dup_x2`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.dup_x2) + [`pop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.pop).

This requires one extra stack slot though.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that!